# Xeon 5649 doesn't POST in Supermicro X8DTE-F motherboard

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, supermicro, xeon

I have a Supermicro board running dual Xeon chips for different little projects. When I originally put it together, I used l5520 chips that are still working in it. With the price drop of 1366 chips, I decided to pick up a couple of hex cores to put in it, 5649's were the cheapest.

So here's my problem, after installing the new chips the motherboard won't post. I reinstalled the old chips, and they work fine, ensuring I didn't mess anything up. I've tried only running a processor in cpu1, I've tried with ecc and non ecc ram. I've tried with a more powerful power supply. Assuming the chips were bad, I contacted the ebay seller and he sent me two more, only to have the same issue. While it's possible that 4 different chips are bad, I find it very unlikely. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Often a bios update is needed when running newer chips in older boards.

Comment: Seems like something obvious I didn't consider. I'll give it a try if the Supermicro page ever comes back up.